# переписать запрос UPDATE ORDER BY из MySQL в PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, запрос

Есть уникальный составной индекс на два поля - (gsort, isort).

В Mysql у меня есть запрос, где update проходил с конца выборки, чтобы избежать ошибки об уникальности уникального индекса. Как мне такое реализовать на PostgreSQL? Спасибо

```
    UPDATE table
    SET isort = isort + 1
    WHERE isort > :isort
        AND gsort = :gsort
    ORDER BY isort DESC;
```

Comment: Можно создать `View`, которая бы содержала всю таблицу, но в DESC сортировке, и уже ее обновлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> чтобы избежать ошибки об уникальности уникального индекса

Давайте собственно эту основную задачу и решать. PostgreSQL позволяет уникальной ограничение сделать отложенным.

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD constraint table_gsort_isort_unique unique (gsort, isort) deferrable initially deferred;
```

Такое ограничение проверяется не в момент записи в таблицу, а при фиксации транзакции. Таким образом:

```
melkij=> create temp table tablename (i serial primary key, gsort int, isort int);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD constraint table_gsort_isort_unique unique (gsort, isort) deferrable initially deferred;
ALTER TABLE
melkij=> insert into tablename (gsort, isort) values (1,1);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> insert into tablename (gsort, isort) values (1,1);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> select * from tablename;
 i | gsort | isort 
---+-------+-------
 1 |     1 |     1
 2 |     1 |     1

melkij=>commit;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_gsort_isort_unique"
```

Таблица внутри транзакции может временно нарушать ограничения уникальности. И вы можете что угодно при этом делать, база вам не позволит только зафиксировать невалидное состояние таблицы. Если на момент `commit` у вас условие уникальности не будет нарушаться - то проблемы нет, транзакция будет зафисирована.